# onResume() only if Resume Activity

Tags: java, android

I need callback if application resume from background but `onResume()` is called always Activity start.

I open a Activity with:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Spedizione.class);
i.putExtra("codice", result.getText());
 startActivity(i);
```

onResume code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Are you sure?").setPositiveButton("Yes", dialogClickListener)
                    .setNegativeButton("No", dialogClickListener).show();
    }
```

When open Activity `onResume()` always call AlertDialog, not only if app is resume from background, why?

I just need callback only if application is reopen from background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OnResume() is an activity lifecycle method which gets called every time. You can handle your condition by putting your call on onRestart() or maintain a boolean to check firstTimeCall or not.

Comment: The documentation explains it: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#alc